# Enter key detection in C

Tags: c, key, enter

I have this program:

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
    char menitem[3][32];
    int i = 0, key;
    strcpy(menitem[0], "This is the first option.");
    strcpy(menitem[1], "And I'm the second option.");
    strcpy(menitem[2], "Don't forget me: The third option!");
    start:
    system("cls");
    printf("%s", menitem[i]);
    ret:
    key = getch();
    if(i == 0)
    {
        switch(key)
        {
            case 80: i++; goto start;
            case '\n': puts("Enter"); getch(); goto start;
            default: goto ret;
        }
    }
    else if(i == 2)
    {
        switch(key)
        {
            case 72: i--; goto start;
            case '\n': puts("Enter"); getch(); goto start;
            default: goto ret;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch(key)
        {
            case 80: i++; goto start;
            case 72: i--; goto start;
            case '\n': puts("Enter"); getch(); goto start;
            default: goto ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't it detect the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key? Am I doing anything wrong?

I tried everything I could find about it.

I tried using the value 10 (as said in the ASCII code), but nothing happens. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, guys. I found out how.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
main()
{
    char menitem[3][32];
    int i = 0, key;
    strcpy(menitem[0], "This is the first option.");
        strcpy(menitem[1], "And I'm the second option.");
        strcpy(menitem[2], "Don't forget me: The third option!");
        start:
        system("cls");
        printf("%s", menitem[i]);
        ret:
        key = getch();
        if(i == 0)
        {
        switch(key)
        {
            case 80: i++; goto start;
            case 13: puts("Enter"); getch(); goto start;
            default: goto ret;
        }
}
else if(i == 2)
switch(key)
{
    case 72: i--; goto start;
    case 13: puts("Enter"); getch(); goto start;
    default: goto ret;
}
else
{
    switch(key)
    {
        case 80: i++; goto start;
        case 72: i--; goto start;
        case 13: puts("Enter"); getch(); goto start;
        default: goto ret;
    }
}
}
```

The value is 13.